# Dummy Variable problem

Tags: regression, self-study, categorical-data

I am doing a regression project based on this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG).

I wonder whether wouldn't it be better to transform the IV *origin* from 1,2,3 to three dummy variables like this:

When the car would be from USA, the IV variables in the model would be like this USA=1, EU=0, JPN=0 etc.

Or it has no impact if the variable *origin* is discrete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to see from your question what you are trying to do, but I will assume that you are trying to estimate something like:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 origin + \dots + \beta_k x_k + u
$$

If that is the case, the estimate of $\beta_1$ is not going to tell you much. Instead (as you say) you should make 2 dummy variables and leave the last as the reference group. Define: $USA = 1$ if that car is from USA, do the same for EU. Then estimate:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 USA + \beta_2 EU + \dots + \beta_k x_k + u
$$

This will give you the marginal effect (which I assume is what you would like to estimate?).

I do not know which software package you are using, but in R you could simple include: as.factor(origin) in the formula. Most software packages has some smiliar feature.

To adress your comment:

Suppose you include origin as is; 1 for USA, 2 for EU and 3 for Japan. Well we could just as easily have reversed that order, such that Japan was 1, USA 2 and EU 3.

Basically we just assigning some ordinal information a number, the numbers could even be -1000 for USA, 500.000 for EU and infinity for Japan. The numbers are completely arbitrary. However, once we plug those ordinal numbers into a regression, then we get an estimate based on numbers - but since the numbers them self does mean anything - neither does the estimate. And the estimate is highly dependent on that arbitrary coding.

Another way to see this is just look at numbers, if they where cardinal measures then the number 3 would imply that Japan is somehow 3 times better USA cars. But (in this case) the “3” just corresponds to Japan. Therefore we include the dummies, on a 0-1 basis.

Comment: Sorry for my vague description.

I use Gretl and yes, you got the point :-)

What do you mean by leaving the last as the reference group? I assumed that I should use all three dummy variables, or shouldn't I?

Comment: Well if you add EU, USA and JAPAN (all defined as in my post). Then you induce perfect multicollinearity, and you cannot estimate the model - try it yourself. Therefore leave one out, Japan in the above, the effect of Japan is then captured by the intercept.

Comment: Just one more question... Why is it actually better to make from this discret variable 2 dummy variables? Besides that somehow intuitively it is better to use dummy ones, but formally explained?